MakeFile is not adding CPP Include flags correctly
I am trying to use SDL library installed with homebrew:
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(){
    
    return 0;
}

This is my make file config.
ADDITIONAL_INCLUDE_PATHS=-I/opt/homebrew/include

cellular_automata: cellular_automata.cpp
    g++ $(ADDITIONAL_INCLUDE_PATHS) cellular_automata.cpp -o cellular_automata

When I compile it manually adding flags in console it works. But not when using make config.
Below is the output of make -n
c++     cellular_automata.cpp   -o cellular_automata

And below is the error when I run using make.
c++     cellular_automata.cpp   -o cellular_automata
cellular_automata.cpp:1:9: fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [cellular_automata] Error 1

Am I doing things wrong or including another directory libraries is not possible?

Something doesn't add up. Are you sure you're running this exact makefile, using exactly make -n?

there is a default rule that is used for .cpp files which usually refers to c++ via $CXX variable. c++ is likely a symlink to either g++ or clang. Something odd is going on with environment. If file named "makefile"? How command is executed (make is affected alot by variables in environment)? What's the environment  state? Is this linux-based OS or something exotic?

e.g., one of thing to look up is env variable named MAKEFILES

I found the issue, I named the makefile as MakeFile instead of  Makefile.

I am running this in MacOs M1 and I installed this with home-brew.

@Swift-FridayPie, that capitalization difference is conventionally significant on Unix systems.  It can be less significant on Mac, but even there, that depends on filesystem type and options.
